Проблема за получением данных от БД Entity Framework 6 на PostgreSQL

Имеется библиотека классов ContextLib. Ранее работала на EF6 с MS SQL, все работало хорошо, недавно по причинным обстоятельствам пришлось менять БД. Решил переводить на PostgreSQL. Выбрал VK Cloud, создал БД, настроил App.Config:


<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PostgreSQL"  providerName="Npgsql" connectionString="Server=83.ххх.ххх.1х5; Port=5хх2; Database=PostgreSQL-хххх; User Id=mastercncDB; Password=ххххххх;" />
</connectionStrings>

<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
</startup>

<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
</entityFramework>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=3.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
        <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
        <add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>

Запустил первую миграцию - всё норм, таблицы в БД создались. вручную создал строку в одной из таблиц, для проверки.
2. Далее, есть приложение, которое использует ContextLib для запросов в БД.
Делаю самый простой запрос:
using (ContextLib context = new ContextLib())
{
   var users = context.Users.ToList();
}

    

В ответ не получаю пустую коллекцию. Ни ошибок, ни исключений. Единственное что обнаружил в момент запроса в Выводе вот это:

"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityFramework".  Вызвано исключение:
"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll Вызвано
исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll
Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в
System.Data.dll Вызвано исключение:
"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll Вызвано
исключение: "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException"
в EntityFramework.dll Вызвано исключение:
"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException" в
EntityFramework.dll Вызвано исключение:
"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException" в
EntityFramework.dll Вызвано исключение:
"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException" в
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Подскажите, что и куда копать? Не могу понять, что не так((
ЗЫ: Вот что выдает весь терминал

"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено "C:\Program
Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.Desktop.dll".
"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll".
"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\Users\графика\source\repos\Therminal\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll".
"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly".  "Therminal.exe" (CLR
v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll".
"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll".
"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll".
"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.resources.dll".
Сборка модуля выполнена без символов. "Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319:
Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll".  "Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll".
"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll".
"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll".
"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll".
"Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089\System.resources.dll".
Сборка модуля выполнена без символов. "Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319:
Therminal.exe). Загружено
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll".  "Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Therminal.exe). Загружено
"EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityFramework".  Вызвано исключение:
"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll Вызвано
исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll
Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в
System.Data.dll Вызвано исключение:
"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll Вызвано
исключение: "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException"
в EntityFramework.dll Вызвано исключение:
"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException" в
EntityFramework.dll Вызвано исключение:
"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException" в
EntityFramework.dll Вызвано исключение:
"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException" в
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll "Therminal.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319:
Therminal.exe). Загружено
"EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-TherminalLibrary".  Программа "[16632]
Therminal.exe" завершилась с кодом -1 (0xffffffff).


Вы когда код копипастите в публичное пространство, конфиденциальные данные для подключения к своим серверам удаляйте в connectionString.

Спасибо за замечание) на этом - не страшно)) тестовая БД)

В терминале больше никакой информации нету? По логу исключение было вызвано, просто не отловлено, поскольку скорее всего произошло вне места, где вы его пытаетесь поймать.

Добавил все выходные

@СергейКостиков, стесняюсь спросить: NPGSQL версии 3.x?? Скорее всего устарела как фекалии мамонта. Может и из-за этого. Попробуйте обновить. Хотя может я и ошибаюсь... сходите сюда, посмотрите https://www.npgsql.org/ef6/index.html
